# Program error: Prelude.read: no parse

Tags: haskell

im new in haskell, im doing my assignment , its about banking system, i get this error when i want to register new account  Program error: Prelude.read: no parse

the code is below:

```
createAcc :: IO()
createAcc = do
        new <- readFile "db.txt"                          --Database named db--
        let new1 = length (func new)
        putStrLn " Enter your Name : "      --write your name--
        name <- getLine
        putStrLn " Enter Balance :"         --enter minimum balance to deposit--
        bal <- getLine
        let bal1 = read bal :: Int                         
        store <- readFile "db.txt"                    --entries comes in  database--
        let store1 = func store
        let store2 = store1 ++ [(new1+1,name,bal1)]
        writeFile "db.txt" (show store2)
func :: String -> [(Int,String,Int)] 
func x = read x:: [(Int,String,Int)]
```

Comment: You can't blithely mix in many lazy `readFile` and `writeFile` calls to the same file.  You need to manage your handles explicitly, make sure they get opened and closed as needed.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably nothing in `db.txt`, hence the read is failing. Try initializing the file with the text "[]".

Also, there's a lot of things to beware of in your approach ... lazy IO is not good for writing reliable programs. You can find out more on the web, but essentially the read may not happen until you actually access the file contents, e.g. with `func`. At a minimum, you should use `deepseq` to force the reads to happen where you expect.